how to install memcached via pecl?
I'm trying to install memcached and am having some difficulty. Here's what I tried:
apt-get update
apt-get install memcached libmemcached-dev libzip-dev
pecl install memcached

pecl install memcached asked me a bunch of questions:
libmemcached directory [no] : /usr/include/libmemcached/
zlib directory [no] :
use system fastlz [no] :
enable igbinary serializer [no] :
enable msgpack serializer [no] :
enable json serializer [no] :
enable server protocol [no] :
enable sasl [yes] :
enable sessions [yes] :

I went with the default answers for each one, save for the first one, and got this error:
checking for libmemcached location... configure: error: Unable to find memcached.h under /usr/include/libmemcached/

ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/memcached/configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/bin/php-config --with-libmemcached-dir=/usr/include/libmemcached/ --with-zlib-dir=no --with-system-fastlz=no --enable-memcached-igbinary=no --enable-memcached-msgpack=no --enable-memcached-json=no --enable-memcached-protocol=no --enable-memcached-sasl=yes --enable-memcached-session=yes' failed

I do not understand this error. When I do find / -type f -name "memcached.h" I get this back:
/usr/include/libmemcached-1.0/struct/memcached.h
/usr/include/libmemcached-1.0/memcached.h
/usr/include/libmemcached/memcached.h

So find can find memcached.h in /usr/include/libmemcached/ but /tmp/pear/temp/memcached/configure can't? That doesn't make any sense.
I'm running all this in sudo bash so permissions shouldn't be an issue.
Any ideas?

Have you check the basic, ping, network, name resolution ?

@Maslie - all of that is fine. Presumably apt-get update would have failed if it wasn't

could you try to use it on root user directly and not with sudo to see if it change anything ?
